# Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: missing the required redirect URI when using Google Account Service (json credentials) to authenticate

Tags: google-api, google-authentication

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//create a Google OAuth client

function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('People API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('secret.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

  $client = getClient();
```

Hmm, so when I run I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: missing the required redire ct URI in C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php:684 Stack trace:
#0 C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Client.php(396): Goo gle\Auth\OAuth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri(Array)
#1 C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\upload.php(32): Google\Client->createAuthUrl()
#2 C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\upload.php(55): getClient()
#3 {main}   thrown in C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php on li ne 684

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: missing the required redirect UR I in C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php:684 Stack trace:
#0 C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Client.php(396): Goo gle\Auth\OAuth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri(Array)
#1 C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\upload.php(32): Google\Client->createAuthUrl()
#2 C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\upload.php(55): getClient()
#3 {main}   thrown in C:\Sources\scripts\script-02\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php on li ne 684
```

I downloaded the credentials and put it inside secret.json, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. There shouldn't be any redirection URL required. I set up a OAuth2 credential on my account, but deleted it when I realized it wasn't meant for server to server connection, or allowing us to upload a file to Google Drive through a simple script.

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/php

The funny thing is that I am using the guide, and did everything their documentation told me to do, and yet it doesn't work at all.

I tried with:

urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

but again it's not working, it can only be used in a native app.

I am thinking something is wrong with the library itself, or Google. Also, whenever I try using this, I often get:

Open the following link in your browser:

And the link doesn't allow me to allow access.

I have no idea how they expect people to use their APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

- Click on the OAuth 2 client ID that you're using.
- Under Authorized redirect URIs
- Click on add URI
- Add the add the uri to this file

`http://localhost/quickstart.php`

- Download the json file again copy the content from that page and past it into `secret.json`

Answer (score 0):

add this lines:
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

reference: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth

Comment: I little of edition in this answer would be nice to see the code better. I've tried to do that, but the queue is always full.